# Gym Equipment in the Oil Tank Room?

Tags: boiler

I am thinking about getting an elliptical for our home.  The only space it will fit is in the room where our oil tanks are located.  Is it okay to workout in this room or is this a health hazard due to the smells/fumes I might be breathing in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because health and safety relating to  the placement of gym equipment, not do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You should seek the advice from a recognized medical practitioner. You wouldn't place your health and well-being on the answers of people who drink beer and chew tobacco all day would you? If I had to offer an answer I would suggest that if you notice any type of petroleum or other noxious fumes it would be wise not to do aerobics there.

Comment: By the same token, if you're smelling any type of petroleum or other noxious fumes in that room, it's a guarantee the same gases are in the whole house and you should find out what's leaking and fix it.